# can't install company app Codename One windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, codenameone

I am successfully able to create and download build from CN1 server for Windows 8.

I am also able to unlock my windows phone (Microsoft Lumia 640 Windows OS 8.1) using 'Windows Phone Developer Registration' utility.

See below image.
[image]

But still I am getting this error, any suggestion please ?

For a testing sake, I created one dummy app just having textfields and even that simple one didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: you have to deploy the app via this tool: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\AppDeploy\AppDeploy.exe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your app on windows phone 8, you have to do the following:

- You must be a registered developer.
- The phone must be registered.
- The phone must be connected to the host computer with the USB cable,
  turned on, and the screen must be unlocked.

To test apps on a Windows Phone 8 device:

- The Windows Phone IP over USB Transport service must be running. This
  service is installed and started when you install the Windows Phone
  SDK 8.0.
- The computer must recognize the connected device. A Windows Phone 8
  phone is listed as a drive in File Explorer.

Read more in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff402565(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for detail, I am now able to install app in phone. But when I run it I am getting error 

`An internal application error occurred

java.lang.RuntimeException Unsupported operation`

Its giving this error for my application and even for an app having just TextField.

Comment: @Shai , I created one new Codename One project and without modifying single character I sent windows build. When I ran that build in same windows phone 8.1 (Microsoft Lumia 640) it gave me same error. I am wondering is it causing after last update of CN1 or before that also it was existing. Thanks.